# How to handle URL and @RequestMapping in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, request-mapping

I have a doubt about the best way to handle the `@RequestMapping`.

For example:

with this url `http://localhost:8080/SpringExample/admin/personaListForm/1` I reach a form, controlled by this @RequestMapping:`@RequestMapping("/admin/personaListForm/{tipoPersona}")`
As you can see "1" is a variable.

This is my form:`<form:form action="personaListFormSent">`

As you can see, If I submit the form, I'll be sent to this url `http://localhost:8080/SpringExample/admin/personaListForm/personaListFormSent` (because of the "/1").
The problem is that i don't want to go there, I want to go to `http://localhost:8080/SpringExample/admin/personaListFormSent`

I may solve the problem editing the form this way `<form:form action="../personaListFormSent">` but it doesn't seem a professional way to handle this problem, since if tomorrow I need to add more variable I'll have to add more "../" to the form tag.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/personaListFormSent`.

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/personaListFormSent">
```

So you will go to http://localhost:8080/SpringExample/personaListFormSent when you post the form.

Answer (score 0):

Send them to action="/personaListFormSent".
'/' is the root of your app, so it doesn't matter which is your context path.

Regards,

Jorge

Comment: action="/personaListFormSent" is not a good idea. 
The form will be send to  http://localhost:8080/personaListFormSent. The best way is use of `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`